# Return only the first instance of a value found in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings that are split in half like the following;

```
fhlist = [['BzRmmzZHzVBzgVQmZ'],['efmt']]
shlist = [['LPtqqffPqWqJmPLlL', ['abcm']]
```

The first half is stored in a list `fhlist` whilst the second in `shlist`.

So the combined string of `fhlist[0]` and `shlist[0]` is `BzRmmzZHzVBzgVQmZLPtqqffPqWqJmPLlL`.

and `fhlist[1]` and `shlist[1]` is `efmtabcm`

I've written some code that iterates through each letter in the first and second half strings, and if any letters appear in both halfs it adds this character to another list `found`;

```
found = []
for i in range(len(fhlist)):
    for char in fhlist[i]:
        if char in shlist[i]:
            found.append(char)
```

However, with the above example, the example list returns me `m m m` as it is returning every instance of the letter occurring, the letter `m` occurs 3 times in the combined string `BzRmmzZHzVBzgVQmZLPtqqffPqWqJmPLlL` I only want to return the code to return `m`

I previously had;

```
found = []
for i in range(len(fhlist)):
    for char in fhlist[i]:
        if char in shlist[i] and char not in found:
            found.append(char)
```

but this essentially 'blacklisted' any characters that appeared in other strings, so if another two strings both contained `m` such as the combined string `efmtabcm`  it would ignore it as this character had already been found.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you care about order? If not, just change `found = []` to `found = set()` and change `found.append(char)` to `found.add(char)`, and you'll get a `set` of the results which are guaranteed duplicate free. In any event, your examples aren't clear enough on what you actually want; can you provide a more clear example input (that shows where problems arise) with observed and desired outputs, rather than describing them in prose with insufficient detail?

Comment: If you care about order, and can rely on using CPython 3.6+ (or any Python 3.7+), a `dict` with garbage keys will solve the problem (it will retain order of first insertion while still discarding duplicates); you can convert back to `list` after.

Comment: Thank you both, the set solution would not work unfortunately, I've edited my post to offer a better explanation. I need to allow duplicate characters, just not if they're from the same index.

Comment: Replace the inner loop with just `found.extend(set(fhlist[i]).intersection(shlist[i]))`? That'll add each character at most once for any given *pair*, but allow other pairings to add the letters again.

Comment: thanks for the help, seems to be giving me an error however `'set' object has no attribute 'extend'`

Comment: You mixed my two suggestions; the second suggestion relies on `found` remaining a `list` (if it's a `set`, you'll overdedupe, which you said was a problem), as in your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding [my suggestion from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74801018/return-only-the-first-instance-of-a-value-found-in-a-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment132012410_74801018) since it apparently solves the problem in the desired way:

To dedupe per pairing, you can replace:

```
found = []
for i in range(len(fhlist)):
    for char in fhlist[i]:
        if char in shlist[i]:
            found.append(char)
```

with (making some slight idiomatic improvements):

```
found = []
for fh, sh in zip(fhlist, shlist):  # Pair them up directly, don't operate by index
    found.extend(set(fh).intersection(sh))
```

or as a possibly too complex listcomp:

```
found = [x for fh, sh in zip(fhlist, shlist) for x in set(fh).intersection(sh)]
```

This gets the unique overlapping items from each pairing (with `set(fh).intersection(sh)`) more efficiently (`O(m+n)` rather than `O(m*n)` in terms of the lengths of each string), then you add them all to `found` in bulk (keeping it as a `list` to avoid deduping *across* pairings).

Comment: thanks very much for such a detailed explanation, really helpful to understand the code rather than just copying it and forgetting about it!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are trying to find common characters between each of the respective strings in fhlist and shlist

You can use `set.intersection` for this after using `zip` on the 2 lists and iterating on them together with a `list comprehension`, as follows -

```
[list(set(f[0]).intersection(s[0])) for f,s in zip(fhlist, shlist)]
```

```
[['m'], ['m']]
```

This works as follows -

```
1. BzRmmzZHzVBzgVQmZ, LPtqqffPqWqJmPLlL -> Common is `m`
2. efmt, abcm -> Common is `m`
...
till end of list
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
fhlist = [['BzRmmzZHzVBzgVQmZ'],['efmt']]

shlist = [['LPtqqffPqWqJmPLlL'], ['abcm']]
found = []
for i in range(len(fhlist)):
    for char in ''.join(fhlist[i]):
        for a in ''.join(shlist[i]):
            if a==char and char not in found:
                
                found.append(char)
        
print(found)
```

Output:

```
['m']
```